# How to print same value in a column while maintaining file in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a file that looks like this (file.txt):

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10    column11    column12    column13    column14    column15    column16
1 chr1_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000280113.2 171773 29 30 0.02 0.33 0.144 0.14 chr1 10000044 A T chr1 10060102 
2 chr7_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000178585.14 -58627 29 30 0.024 0.26 0.16 0.15 chr7 10000044 A T chr7 18054785
4 chr1_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000280113.2 89708 29 30 0.0 0.03 -0.0 0.038 chr1 10000044 A T chr1 18054638
5 chr1_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000231181.1 -472482 29 30 0.02 0.16 0.11 0.07 chr1 10000044 A T chr1 18052645
6 chr8_304959_A_T_b38 ENSG00000178585.14 -586 60 30 0.026 0.76 0.16 0.15 chr7 10000044 A T chr7 18054785
```

I want to print the same values in column 3 so that the output looks like this. For one unique value one output would be:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10    column11    column12    column13    column14    column15    column16
1 chr1_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000280113.2 171773 29 30 0.02 0.33 0.144 0.14 chr1 10000044 A T chr1 10060102 
4 chr1_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000280113.2 89708 29 30 0.0 0.03 -0.0 0.038 chr1 10000044 A T chr1 18054638
```

For the second unique value in column 3 it should be

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10    column11    column12    column13    column14    column15    column16
2 chr7_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000178585.14 -58627 29 30 0.024 0.26 0.16 0.15 chr7 10000044 A T chr7 18054785
6 chr8_304959_A_T_b38 ENSG00000178585.14 -586 60 30 0.026 0.76 0.16 0.15 chr7 10000044 A T chr7 18054785
```

Comment: You have to establish what you are doing with the other columns' data. Like, in column 4, it appears that your desired output throws away the value 89708. Why? What is the rule there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You can split by each unique value using `group_split`, which will print the groups.

```
library(dplyr)

group_split(df, column3)
```

Or in base R:

```
split(df, f = df$column3)
```

***Output***

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 16
  column1 column2               column3            column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10 column11 column12 column13 column14 column15 column16
    <int> <chr>                 <chr>                <int>   <int>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       <int> <chr>    <lgl>    <chr>       <int>
1       2 chr7_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000178585.14  -58627      29      30   0.024    0.26    0.16     0.15 chr7     10000044 A        TRUE     chr7     18054785
2       6 chr8_304959_A_T_b38   ENSG00000178585.14    -586      60      30   0.026    0.76    0.16     0.15 chr7     10000044 A        TRUE     chr7     18054785

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 × 16
  column1 column2               column3           column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10 column11 column12 column13 column14 column15 column16
    <int> <chr>                 <chr>               <int>   <int>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       <int> <chr>    <lgl>    <chr>       <int>
1       5 chr1_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000231181.1 -472482      29      30    0.02    0.16    0.11     0.07 chr1     10000044 A        TRUE     chr1     18052645

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 × 16
  column1 column2               column3           column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10 column11 column12 column13 column14 column15 column16
    <int> <chr>                 <chr>               <int>   <int>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       <int> <chr>    <lgl>    <chr>       <int>
1       1 chr1_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000280113.2  171773      29      30    0.02    0.33   0.144    0.14  chr1     10000044 A        TRUE     chr1     10060102
2       4 chr1_10000044_A_T_b38 ENSG00000280113.2   89708      29      30    0       0.03   0        0.038 chr1     10000044 A        TRUE     chr1     18054638
```

If you need to write each unique dataframe to a file, then you can use `lapply`. Here, I use the unique names from `column3` to give a name to each txt file.

```
mylist <- split(df , f = df$column3)

lapply(names(mylist), function(x) write.table(mylist[[x]], file=paste(x,".txt"), sep="\t"))
```

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(column1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L), column2 = c("chr1_10000044_A_T_b38", 
"chr7_10000044_A_T_b38", "chr1_10000044_A_T_b38", "chr1_10000044_A_T_b38", 
"chr8_304959_A_T_b38"), column3 = c("ENSG00000280113.2", "ENSG00000178585.14", 
"ENSG00000280113.2", "ENSG00000231181.1", "ENSG00000178585.14"
), column4 = c(171773L, -58627L, 89708L, -472482L, -586L), column5 = c(29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 60L), column6 = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), column7 = c(0.02, 
0.024, 0, 0.02, 0.026), column8 = c(0.33, 0.26, 0.03, 0.16, 0.76
), column9 = c(0.144, 0.16, 0, 0.11, 0.16), column10 = c(0.14, 
0.15, 0.038, 0.07, 0.15), column11 = c("chr1", "chr7", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr7"), column12 = c(10000044L, 10000044L, 10000044L, 
10000044L, 10000044L), column13 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
    column14 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), column15 = c("chr1", 
    "chr7", "chr1", "chr1", "chr7"), column16 = c(10060102L, 
    18054785L, 18054638L, 18052645L, 18054785L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I  have changed my question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @HKJ3 I've updated my answer. But it's still not totally clear if you are just wanting to print these to the console or if you are wanting a different output format.

Comment: How can I list each output as seperate files - rather than one big output in one file?

Comment: @HKJ3 I've added how to output each unique value to its own text file right above "Data" in my answer. But not sure what format you need this to be in, so you might need to update the arguments in `write.table` to what you need.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the answer. what I do notice is that an extra number is inserted in the output in the first column with no header and therefore, the column names have shifted once to the right meaning the values don't align to the correct column name. How can I get rid of this extra inserted column with numbers.

Comment: I've put row.names=FALSE and it still doesnt work